# NameError: global name is not defined when calling @staticmethod in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, global, static-methods

I am making a small project and I have a main file, called `blog.py` and a separate file called `users.py` in a folder called `source`.

The layout of the project so far is:

```
MainFolder
    |_blog.py
    |
    |_source
        |_user.py
```

So, my `user.py` is very simple and it has a `@staticmethod`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class User(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pwd_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def searchByUsername(anUserName):
        usersList = db.GqlQuery("select * from User where username='" + anUserName + "'")
        user = None
        for theUser in usersList:
            user = theUser
        return user
```

In my `blog.py` file I try to call that method by making `User.searchByUsername(anUserName)`, however when I do so everythning blows up and I end up with an error (**check last 2 lines**):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/hw5/blog.py", line 202, in post
    user = User.searchByUsername(username)
NameError: global name 'User' is not defined
```

I am using `from source import user` in my `blog.py` file, and the sources folder also has the `__init__.py` blank folder, so I know that file is being correctly imported.

Further more, if I just copy/paste the contents of the `user.py` file into the `blog.py` file everything works fine (but the I the code gets big and not organized). how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `from source import user`, you are importing the *module* `user`, not the class `User` inside it.  If you want to import that class, you should do `from source.user import User`.  Or you can do `from source import user` and then refer to the class as `user.User`.

The staticmethod has nothing to do with it.  As the error message suggests, the issue is that it does not know what `User` is, so it can't even begin to call a method of that class.

Comment: Wow, I had not idea about the module thing. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have forgotten to import User into blog.py:

```
from source.user import User
```